# Dynamically adding epics during runtime calls the newly added epics multiple times

Tags: redux, rxjs, redux-observable

My work is based on these directions: https://redux-observable.js.org/docs/recipes/AddingNewEpicsAsynchronously.html

So I am having an issue with getting this test to execute the epics, am I missing something?  In any case the code explains what is going on...

I would expect my call of to `store.dispatch({type:'GO'})` to chain all of my epics.  I see my reducer is wired up but the Epics do not get called.

fyi I need this to work to test what I think is a bug.  In my actual application when I dynamically load a new epic using `epicLoader$.next(<someepic>)` the dynamically loaded epic is now called twice... but I can't prove that until this test works.

As a workaround I have manually added the epics that I wanted to add dynamically and it is working fine but this isn't possible past my POC phase.  I'll need to load the epics from separate files that will be pushed to the app.

Help me Obi wan...

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mapTo';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import {combineReducers, createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import { createEpicMiddleware,combineEpics } from 'redux-observable';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

test('dynamicly loading epic calls it twice',done => {
  let epic1 = (action$)=>action$
    .ofType('GO')
    .do((action)=>console.log('epic1',action))
    .mapTo({type:'EPIC1'});

  let epic2 = (action$,{epicLoader$})=>action$
    .ofType('EPIC1')
    .do((action)=>console.log('epic2',action))
    .do(()=>epicLoader$.next(epic3))
    .do(()=>epicLoader$.next(epic4))
    .mapTo({type:'EPIC2'});

  let epic3 = (action$)=>action$
    .ofType('EPIC2')
    .do((action)=>console.log('epic3',action))
    .mapTo({type:'EPIC3'});

  let epic4 = (action$)=>action$
    .ofType('EPIC2')
    .do((action)=>console.log('epic4',action))
    .do(()=>done())
    .mapTo({type:'EPIC4'});


  const epic$ = new BehaviorSubject(combineEpics({epic1,epic2}));
  const rootEpic = (action$, store, args) =>
    epic$.mergeMap(epic =>
      epic(action$, store, args)
    );

  const epicMiddleware = createEpicMiddleware(rootEpic,
    { dependencies: {
      epicLoader$: epic$,
    }});

  const reducer =(state = {},action)=>{
    console.log('reducer',action);
    return state;
   };

  const store = createStore(
    combineReducers({
      reducer
    }),
    applyMiddleware(epicMiddleware)
  );
  //start up the chain of events.
  store.dispatch({type:'GO'});
});
```

Comment: OK I've confirmed that dynamically added epics are in-fact getting called with the same action twice in quick succession.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I see two issues with the provided code:

#### Providing object to `combineEpics` instead of just arguments

You're passing an object to `combineEpics`, but it's supposed to just be plain old arguments. This is different than `combineReducers`

```
// bad
const epic$ = new BehaviorSubject(combineEpics({epic1,epic2}));
// good
const epic$ = new BehaviorSubject(combineEpics(epic1,epic2));
```

Support for passing an object has been discussed here: https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable/issues/58. It hasn't been supported yet because the keys would be meaningless, unlike with `combineReducers`.

This actually does throw an error when the rootEpic is subscribed to, but it's unfortunately swallowed because of a [outstanding bug in rxjs](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2813)

#### destructuring of `store` instead of the third dependencies argument

```
// bad
let epic2 = (action$,{epicLoader$})=>action$
// good
let epic2 = (action$,store,{epicLoader$})=>action$
```

---

Once these are fixed, it appears to work as desired:

I did notice that `epic4` is listening for `EPIC2`, which you might have actually meant to listen for `EPIC3` maybe?

[image]

Comment: Yes this is the solution.

Comment: @RobelRobelLingstuyl yay! so glad, thanks for confirming.